# JavaScript access to parent from child with created property

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

The following code works perfectly:

```
    function Shape(){}
    Shape.prototype.name = 'Shape';
    Shape.prototype.toString = function(){
        return this.constructor.parent
            ? this.constructor.parent.toString() + ',' + this.name
            : this.name;
    };

    function TwoDShape(){}
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = Shape.prototype;
    TwoDShape.prototype = new F();
    TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;
    TwoDShape.parent = Shape.prototype;
    TwoDShape.prototype.name = '2D Shape';

    var my = new TwoDShape();

    console.log(my.toString());
```

It prints out the following: Shape,2D Shape.

However could somebody explain what is actually going on with the following?

return this.constructor.parent (I have changed it from uber to parent which makes more sense)

Comment: Looks like a very bad idea to me, invoking methods on prototype objects instead of instances. Where did you get that code from?

Comment: note that `return this.constructor.parent` isn't a statement on it's own, instead `this.constructor.parent` is the condition in the [ternary (`?:`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: I got this code from a new book called "Object-oriented javascript" by Stoyan Stefanov and Kumar Chetan Sharma